# mgt-spfx web part error: Manifest not found for component id and version "2.3.0"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I have a SharePoint web part where I'm using the MGT Person component.

`gulp serve` is working just fine.

However, when I bundle/package/deploy the app and add my web part to the page, I get the following error:

Manifest not found for component id "78b11c7d-7ca8-47cb-a93c-d3beabb519a1" and version "2.3.0".

Looking at the packaged files shows me that 78b11c7d-7ca8-47cb-a93c-d3beabb519a1 represents `mgt-spfx` library and it is indeed version 2.3.0.  I have no idea how to proceed at this point.  Any ideas on how to debug?

Comment: Are you able to bundle/package/deploy our sample:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/samples/sp-webpart
by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I had this problem this week and I solved it by uploading the corresponding [mgt-spfx sppkg](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/releases) to the app catalog in tenant level.
This error occurs if you don't have the sppkg of the version used in your webpart installed in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I resolved it by changing the id in the webpart manifest.json with the product id present in the app catalog. [image: webpart manifest.json]